# Blender Import "Own Particles" for use in Cell Fracture

Tags: blender, voronoi

I am trying to use the Point Source "Own Particles" feature in the Cell Fracture module of Blender.

I am loading a simple object with Import Wavefront (.obj)

I would now like to import a list of defined points to use in the cell fracture algorithm.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

The 'Own Particles' option allows you to use points generated by a particle system attached to the object, not a list of points imported separately.

The 'Child Verts' option allows you to use the vertices of child objects as the source, this should allow you to import the points as separate objects, parent them to the original mesh by selecting the point object/s then shift select the original mesh and press <kbd>⎈ Ctrl</kbd><kbd>P</kbd> and select object. Parenting is explained in [more detail here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/26108/935).

[image]

Once you have setup the parenting choose 'Child Verts' in the cell fracture options.